# How are you getting trained in light of tech conferences getting cancelled?

Tags: distributed-training

Just helping figure out how to keep software engineers at my company trained. How are you getting trained in light of working from home and / or tech conferences getting cancelled for the foreseeable future?

Answer (score 0):

Tech conferences I would consider of minimal value when it comes to training a software engineer. There is plenty of courses you can do online in terms of training. You could ask your engineers to complete online courses. There is plural sight, safari, YouTube, LinkedIn now has training courses.